# Php class exception error message

Tags: php, wordpress, exception

I'm struggling with fixing this class exception error. If anyone could help it would be greatly appreciated, Thanks!

#### BACKGROUND INFO:

After installing a Dashnex plugin on my wordpress site & then uninstalling WP Quick cache I am getting this error message. Please note that quick cache is fully uninstalled & the wp-config.php file includes no quick cache instructions.

#### ERROR MESSAGE:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Class \quick_cache does not exist' in /home/cal108/public_html/wp-content/plugins/dashnex-plugin/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/Driver/AnnotationDriver.php:246 Stack trace: #0 /home/cal108/public_html/wp-content/plugins/dashnex-plugin/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/Driver/AnnotationDriver.php(246): ReflectionClass->__construct('\quick_cache') #1 /home/cal108/public_html/wp-content/plugins/dashnex-plugin/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/AbstractClassMetadataFactory.php(113): Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver->getAllClassNames() #2 /home/cal108/public_html/wp-content/plugins/dashnex-plugin/DashNex/Doctrine/MagicSchema.php(18): Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\AbstractClassMetadataFactory->getAllMetadata() #3 /home/cal108/public_html/wp-content/plugins/dashnex-plugin/DashNex/Doctrine/MagicSchema.php(37): DashNex\Doctrine\MagicSchema->Get in /home/cal108/public_html/wp-content/plugins/dashnex-plugin/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/Driver/AnnotationDriver.php on line 246
```

**AnnotationDriver.php Line 246**

```
$rc = new \ReflectionClass($className);
```

**AnnotationDriver.php File**

```
    <?php

abstract class AnnotationDriver implements MappingDriver
{
    /**
     * The AnnotationReader.
     *
     * @var AnnotationReader
     */
    protected $reader;

    /**
     * The paths where to look for mapping files.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $paths = array();

    /**
     * The paths excluded from path where to look for mapping files.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $excludePaths = array();

    /**
     * The file extension of mapping documents.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $fileExtension = '.php';

    /**
     * Cache for AnnotationDriver#getAllClassNames().
     *
     * @var array|null
     */
    protected $classNames;

    /**
     * Name of the entity annotations as keys.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $entityAnnotationClasses = array();

    /**
     * Initializes a new AnnotationDriver that uses the given AnnotationReader for reading
     * docblock annotations.
     *
     * @param AnnotationReader  $reader The AnnotationReader to use, duck-typed.
     * @param string|array|null $paths  One or multiple paths where mapping classes can be found.
     */
    public function __construct($reader, $paths = null)
    {
        $this->reader = $reader;
        if ($paths) {
            $this->addPaths((array) $paths);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Appends lookup paths to metadata driver.
     *
     * @param array $paths
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function addPaths(array $paths)
    {
        $this->paths = array_unique(array_merge($this->paths, $paths));
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves the defined metadata lookup paths.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getPaths()
    {
        return $this->paths;
    }

    /**
     * Append exclude lookup paths to metadata driver.
     *
     * @param array $paths
     */
    public function addExcludePaths(array $paths)
    {
        $this->excludePaths = array_unique(array_merge($this->excludePaths, $paths));
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve the defined metadata lookup exclude paths.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getExcludePaths()
    {
        return $this->excludePaths;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve the current annotation reader
     *
     * @return AnnotationReader
     */
    public function getReader()
    {
        return $this->reader;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the file extension used to look for mapping files under.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getFileExtension()
    {
        return $this->fileExtension;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the file extension used to look for mapping files under.
     *
     * @param string $fileExtension The file extension to set.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function setFileExtension($fileExtension)
    {
        $this->fileExtension = $fileExtension;
    }

    /**
     * Returns whether the class with the specified name is transient. Only non-transient
     * classes, that is entities and mapped superclasses, should have their metadata loaded.
     *
     * A class is non-transient if it is annotated with an annotation
     * from the {@see AnnotationDriver::entityAnnotationClasses}.
     *
     * @param string $className
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function isTransient($className)
    {
        $classAnnotations = $this->reader->getClassAnnotations(new \ReflectionClass($className));

        foreach ($classAnnotations as $annot) {
            if (isset($this->entityAnnotationClasses[get_class($annot)])) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function getAllClassNames()
    {
        if ($this->classNames !== null) {
            return $this->classNames;
        }

        if (!$this->paths) {
            throw MappingException::pathRequired();
        }

        $classes = array();
        $includedFiles = array();

        foreach ($this->paths as $path) {
            if ( ! is_dir($path)) {
                throw MappingException::fileMappingDriversRequireConfiguredDirectoryPath($path);
            }

            $iterator = new \RegexIterator(
                new \RecursiveIteratorIterator(
                    new \RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path, \FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS),
                    \RecursiveIteratorIterator::LEAVES_ONLY
                ),
                '/^.+' . preg_quote($this->fileExtension) . '$/i',
                \RecursiveRegexIterator::GET_MATCH
            );

            foreach ($iterator as $file) {
                $sourceFile = $file[0];

                if ( ! preg_match('(^phar:)i', $sourceFile)) {
                    $sourceFile = realpath($sourceFile);
                }

                foreach ($this->excludePaths as $excludePath) {
                    $exclude = str_replace('\\', '/', realpath($excludePath));
                    $current = str_replace('\\', '/', $sourceFile);

                    if (strpos($current, $exclude) !== false) {
                        continue 2;
                    }
                }

                require_once $sourceFile;

                $includedFiles[] = $sourceFile;
            }
        }

        $declared = get_declared_classes();

        foreach ($declared as $className) {
            $rc = new \ReflectionClass($className);
            $sourceFile = $rc->getFileName();
            if (in_array($sourceFile, $includedFiles) && ! $this->isTransient($className)) {
                $classes[] = $className;
            }
        }

        $this->classNames = $classes;

        return $classes;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I WAS ABLE TO SOLVE MY PROBLEM. HELP NOT NEEDED ANYMORE :)

FOR ANYONE THIS MAY STILL HELP:

I DISABLED ALL OF MY PLUGINS BY RENAMING THEM IT IN CPANEL, THEN BROUGHT EACH ONE ONLINE AGAIN TO KNOW IF THE DASHNEX PLUGIN WAS THE CULPRIT. IT WAS. THEN RENAMED ALL PLUGINS AGAIN & ALL WORKING FINE.

I DON'T THINK THE DASHNEX PLUGIN LIKED MY UNINSTALLING WP QUICK CACHE. BUT REINSTALLING IT AFTER WP QUCIK CACHE HAD ALREADY BEEN UNINSTALLED WORKED FINE. THIS IS THE 2ND TIME I'VE HAD PROBLEMS WHEN QUICK CACHE HAS BEEN UNINSTALLED SO BE WARY OF IT. MAYBE BEST TO JUST DEACTIVATE IT & ONLY UNINSTALL IT ON A BRAND NEW SITE BEFORE INSTALLING ANY OTHER PLUGINS.

DIDN'T END UP NEEDING TO TWEAK THE PHP CODE.